# Filtering Scenario outline by Line Number of example table in karate

Tags: cucumber, karate

is it possible to filter the table by line number in karate?

```
 Scenario Outline: name is <name> and age is <age>
  * def temp = '<name>'
  * match temp == name
  * match temp == __row.name

  Examples:
    | name | age |
    | Bob  | 5   |
    | Nyan | 6   |

@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/feature/scenarios.feature:2")
```

The above command should only run 2nd row of the mentioned table

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works in 0.9.5.RC4

```
@RunWith(Karate.class)
@KarateOptions(features = "classpath:com/myco/test.feature:9")
public class TestRunner {        

}
```

====

```
Feature:

Scenario Outline:
* print x

Examples:
| x |
| 1 |
| 2 |
```